# jQuery rebinding .click?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple clicks, that I have to unbind once clicked on, but I need to rebind the button for the links.

Here is an example :

```
$('.001').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).unbind('click');
      jQuery('.hide').hide();
      jQuery('.show').show();
      jQuery(this).find('.show').hide();
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').load('pages/001.html');
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').show();

    }); 

    $('.002').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).unbind('click');
      jQuery('.hide').hide();
      jQuery('.show').show();
      jQuery(this).find('.show').hide();
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').load('pages/002.html');
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').show();
    });
```

So when I click on .001 it loads a page with a different jQuery action in it (a slider), so I must unbind the click on .001 (hence the jQuery(this).unbind('click');), BUT when I click on .002 I must rebind the .click on .001. This must be done with vars because this can go from 001 to 999.

Any tips ?

Comment: Have a look at [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). It might help you to execute event only once per each element.

Comment: Don't tell me you have 999 handlers.. from what I see.. it seems like it can be reused with slight modification.

Comment: @VisioN Just tried .one, does the same thing, I can't reclick after i've clicked once.

Comment: @Vega no of course, hence why I'm here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bind and rebind handlers again and again. Just store the identifier of the activated item somewhere, then check for it in each click handler. Like this:

```
var active;
$('.some_class').click(function() {
  if (this.className === active) {
    return false;
  }
  active = this.className;
  ...
});
```

Also, I'd highly recommend assigning one and only one function as event handler for all the items in question, forking its actions based on external attribute. Like this:

```
<a class="first" data-url-to-go="/first.html">Some Link</a>
<a class="second" data-url-to-go="/second.html">Some Other Link</a>
...
var active;
$('.first, .second').click(function() {
  if (this.className === active) {
    return false; 
  }
  active = this.className;
  var $this = $(this), 
      url = $this.data('urlToGo');
  ...
});
```

Here's a [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LmRe/) that illustrates this concept.

Comment: Ok this works great, just a quick question (hopefully you'll be able to answer), how can I use urlToGo with 3 digits ? I have 001 and he alerts only "1". Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=1;i<1000;i++){
    var query_str
    var page_to_load;
    if(i<10){
        query_str = ".00"+i
        page_to_load = "pages/00" + i + ".html"
    }
    else if(i>10 && i<100){
        query_str = ".0"+i
        page_to_load = "pages/0" + i + ".html"
    }
    else{
        query_str = "."+i
        page_to_load = "pages/" + i + ".html"
    }


     $(quer_str).click(function(){
      jQuery(this).unbind('click');
      jQuery('.hide').hide();
      jQuery('.show').show();
      jQuery(this).find('.show').hide();
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').load(page_to_load);
      jQuery(this).find('.hide').show();

    }); 

}
```

this will not be good performance but this is what you asked for

Comment: I think this is what you wanted

Comment: This looks good, but the problem is pages/001.html changed each time too (002, 003 etc etc)

Comment: And you want to rebind ".001" when ".002" is clicked?

Comment: That's an amazingly inefficient approach, to say the least. Why create N functions, each for a new element, instead of using a single function making URL from its argument? It should be much better both speed- and memory-wise.